# AudioManger FLAG_SHOW_UI not showing the system volume menu in Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

```
AudioManager ad = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (ad != null) {
        ad.adjustVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
    }
```

This code doesn't showing volume menu in Samsung devices.
Tried with Galaxy S10,A71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case `STREAM_MUSIC` you need to use like below code -

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Hope this will help you.